# Decrypt Card Number

Tags: c#

I'm helping some students do some programming work and would like to know how to decrypt a credit card number after it has been encrypted. Here is the encrypt property:

```
public string Encrypt(string ccNum)
{
    ccNum = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt64(ccNum) * 13) + 43);
    return ccNum;
}
```

I figured the decrypt property would be the reverse of the encrypt, but it doesn't work.  Here is my code for the decrypt property:

```
public string Decrypt(string ccNum) //DOESN'T DECRYPT
{
    string decCCNum = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt64(ccNum) - 43) / 13);
    MessageBox.Show("Customer Name: " + FirstName + " " + LastName + "\n" + 
           "Encypted Card #: " + Encrypt(ccNum) + "\n" + 
           "Decrypted Card #: " + decCCNum , "Customer Info", 
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    return ccNum;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are returning `ccNum` in your `Decrypt` method, shouldn't you be returning `decCCNum`?

Comment: this is simple math problem: x = (y * z) + w , solve for y: y = -w/z + x/z

Comment: @NMeneses I recommend giving a trial of Resharper a go. It is really helpful for these kinds of mistakes since it shows the `decCCNum` variable in a different colour (so I can spot that I forgot to return it).

Comment: Does the ccNum string have leading zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple math problem, as you have already:

> x = (y * z) + w, solve for y: y = (x - w) / z

I suggest you write unit tests as well to assert your code works (like others have suggested, you are returning the original encrypted number):

```
public static class CreditCardEncryptor
{
    public static string Encrypt(string ccNum)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(ccNum) * 13 + 43);
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string encryptedCcNum)
    {
        return Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt64(encryptedCcNum) - 43) / 13);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class CreditCardEncryptorTests
{
    [TestCase("5105105105105100")]
    [TestCase("4012888888881881")]
    [TestCase("4222222222222")]
    [TestCase("4111111111111111")]
    public void WhenIDecryptItShouldReturnCcNumber(string ccNum)
    {
        Assert.That(ccNum, Is.EqualTo(CreditCardEncryptor.Decrypt(CreditCardEncryptor.Encrypt(ccNum))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To decrypt, the parameter should be a encrypted number, your method should be something like this:

```
public string Decrypt(string encryptedNumber)
{
    string decCCNum = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt64(encryptedNumber) - 43) / 13);
    MessageBox.Show("Customer Name: " + FirstName + " " + LastName + "\n" + 
       "Encypted Card #: " + encryptedNumber + "\n" + 
       "Decrypted Card #: " + decCCNum , "Customer Info", 
       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
return decCCNum;
}
```

Comment: Because he is trying to decrypt the ccNum that is the credit card number (without encrypt) and returning that number. Or maybe I didn't understand very well...